# $f(z)$ analytic in the panctured disk $\{|z|<1 \}\setminus\{0\}, \text{Im}(f(z))>0$, then $z=0$ is removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the panctured disk $\{|z|<1 \}\setminus\{0\}$ and let $\text{Im}(f(z))>0$. Prove $z=0$ is removable singularity.

I try to show that $f(z)$ is bounded near $z=0$ but there don't seem to be enough details to do this. I then thought $f(z)\ne 0$ in the domain which means considering $g(z)={1\over f(z)}$ is an option. The problem is that I can't tell for sure that $z=0$ is an essential singularity, and I can't get any bounds. I could use some help.

**Edit:** it can't be essential, for the imaginary part of the image is greater than 0.

Comment: do you mean $Im(f(z))>0$?

Comment: Yes, I do, terribly sorry for that.

Comment: Hint: Put $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)+i}$

Comment: I think $g(x)=\exp{(i\cdot f(x))}$ will be more helpful here. please read again about Liouville's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: How can I tell whether or not $f$ is entire?

Comment: forget it, what you need is proving [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) (that you can do using the Liouville theorem) and apply it to $g(z) = e^{i f(z)}$

Comment: So $g$ is bounded because $e^{-Im(f(z))}<1$?